# In PHP, check all values from array in another, find values that doesn't exist in the second array

Tags: php, arrays

I've been struggling with this question.

I have two arrays $old_images_array and $product_images_array.
What I want is, to search on the $old_images_array for everything inside $product_images_array.

If a value is in the $old_images_array, but isn't in the $product_images_array, delete a file with that value as name.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you give us some PHP source as to what you've written already?

Comment: Thanks.

This is what I have right now.
$diff = array_diff($old_images_array, $product_images_array);

 foreach ($diff as $filename) {
     if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . DS . $filename)) {
   unlink(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . DS . $filename);
     }
 }

The path is correct, I already tested it with a especific file.
Still it doesn't delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

look at the array_diff() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would be to use the array_diff function.  Something like this:

```
$diff = array_diff($old_images_array, $product_images_array);

foreach ($diff as $filename) {
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
    }
}
```